# DataGridView Freeze UI when loading big table

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, datagridview

The following code freeze my UI.

```
'Load DataTable using backgroundworker with 15,000 records
...

'On backgroundworker's run completed event, pass loaded table
'and fill datagridview control

dim t as DataTable
t = DirectCast(e.Result, DataTable)

'This part takes very long and FREEZE UI
gridview.DataSource = t
```

Does anybody has a solution to fix the loading part? There is no asynchronous load method in DataGridView and I am unable to put gridView.DataSource = t in backgroundworker thread as it will conflict with the UI thread. Please help..

Comment: it seems that you need to study first the [Threading](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet)

Comment: Why would you want to display 15,000 records in one go? Limit the query to x results, and have prev/next buttons to reload

Comment: i think there is nothing wrong with the backgroundworker part. it is working perfectly. the issue is when assigning the data fetched by backgroundworker to datagridview control. It is taking forever to display the data.

Comment: 15,000 records are just sample data for simulating situation where user load too much data at a time.

Comment: Then make sure you dont allow the user to request that mach data in one go, limit it to a maximum amount, as i suggested. painting 15k lines of data on screen is going to be slow, and pointless, so dont do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Datagridview virtual mode solves the problem.